# msdeploy.exe in xp-error occurs(testing an application for Web PI)

Tags: web-platform-installer

when i try running this batch script

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\msdeploy.exe" ^
 -verb:sync -source:Package="C:\JumptreeTrialSP2V1.3.0.0.zip" ^
 -dest:auto ^
 -setParam:dbAdminUsername="sa" ^
 -setParam:dbAdminPassword="brain" ^
 -setParam:dbUsername="sa" ^
 -setParam:dbUserPassword="brain" ^
 -setParam:dbServer=".\sqlexpress" ^
 -setParam:dbName="JumptreeV12"  ^
 -setParam:AppPath="Default Web Site/Jumptree"
```

there is an error "Unrecognized argument dbAdminUsername"
I m trying to test this application to verify if it is packaged the right way for Web PI.
I m using XP SP3.